# serilog possible to change email format

Tags: serilog

we are currently using Serilog for logging errors to our db.  We would also like to use it send our dev team an email when the error occurs.  currently we are using the following format:

```
string LogMessageTemplate = "{Username}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Stack}{NewLine}{ErrMsg}{NewLine}{ErrSource}{NewLine}{NewLine}{Route}{NewLine}{Request}{NewLine}{Browser}{NewLine}{ClientIPAddress}"
```

Using Serilog.Sinks.Email we can get emails, but is there a way to format it to look better?  Maybe have it use a template with HTML/CSS for emails?